# How can I redirect uv_tty (LIBUV) console output to AllocConsole()?

Tags: c++, stdio, libuv

I'm moving from C++ console application to win32 application (SUBSYSTEM:Windows).
My application have a 3rd project with many console log using libuv, It's working on Win32 console application, But when I change project to Win32 GUI it's not work, No any 3rd project console output, It has only output from my log use printf.

I'm working on VS2017 and I use AllocConsole() + redirect stdin, stdout to make printf work, But not work for uv_tty console output.

How can I redirect console output from uv_tty to AllocConsole()?